# Como corregir problemas de conversiones (casts) con PDO php en base de datos postgresql

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, pdo

hice la prueba de la siguiente consulta directamente en la base de datos y funciona perfecto:

```
UPDATE alertasdocumentos SET alert_disparada_diez = true
                        WHERE alert_activa = true AND ((alert_fecha - 10)  = (current_date))  
                        AND alert_disparada_diez = false
```

Pero al momento de ejecutarla con PDO mediante el siguiente código, obtengo el siguiente error:

Código:

```
    $alert_activa = true;
    $alert_disparada_diez = false;
    $dias = 10;
    $alert = true;

    $sql1 = " UPDATE alertasdocumentos SET alert_disparada_diez = :alert
                        WHERE alert_activa = :alert_activa AND ((alert_fecha - :dias)  = (current_date))  
                        AND alert_disparada_diez = :alert_disparada_diez ";

    $q1 = $pdo->prepare($sql1);
    $q1->bindParam(":alert", $alert, PDO::PARAM_BOOL);
    $q1->bindParam(":alert_activa", $alert_activa, PDO::PARAM_BOOL);
    $q1->bindParam(":alert_disparada_diez", $alert_disparada_diez, PDO::PARAM_BOOL);
    $q1->bindParam(":dias", $dias, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $q1->execute();
```

Error:

```
ERROR: SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = date
LINE 2: ... WHERE alert_activa = $2 AND ((alert_fecha - $3)  = (current...
                                                         ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit 
type casts.
```

He tratado de usar cast de esta manera:

```
(alert_fecha - :dias)::DATE = current_date 
TO_DATE(alert_fecha - :dias) = current_date
```

Pero me indica un error que no se puede hacer cast sobre los parámetros integer y date

Answer (score 0):

Bueno si no dio intenta haciendo otra cosa que es lo mismo si restas las dos fechas debería darte el numero de días que estas enviando como parametro, queda así :

```
$sql1 = " UPDATE alertasdocumentos SET alert_disparada_diez = :alert
            WHERE alert_activa = :alert_activa 
            AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, alert_fecha, current_date) = :dias   
            AND alert_disparada_diez = :alert_disparada_diez ";
```

espero te ayude saludos.

Comment: Obtengo el siguiente ERROR: SQLSTATE[42846]: Cannot coerce: 7 ERROR:  cannot cast type integer to date

Comment: ya lo corregí perdón.

Comment: Funciona bien en la base de datos, pero por PDO sigue saliendo el mismo error ERROR: SQLSTATE[42846]: Cannot coerce: 7 ERROR:  cannot cast type integer to date
LINE 2: ...                     WHERE alert_activa = $2 AND (CAST ((ale...

Comment: si no te funcion el **TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, alert_fecha, current_date) ** utiliza **DATEDIFF(alert_fecha, current_date)** no tengo mysql para ver si funciona pero me dices como te va.